# Prove the center of direct product $H$ x $K$ is $Z(H$ x $K)$ = $Z(H)$ x $Z(K)$

Tags: group-theory

the question I've been given is below:

Recall that the centre of a group G is the subgroup

$Z(G)$ = $\{g ∈ G :$ for all $h ∈ G, gh = hg\}$.

Let $H$ and $K$ be any two finite groups. Then the center of the direct
product $H × K$ is

$Z(H × K) = $ $\{(h, k) :$ for all $(x, y) ∈ H × K, (h, k)(x, y) = (x, y)(h, k)\}$.

Prove that $Z(H × K) = Z(H) × Z(K)$ by proving separately that

• $Z(H × K) ⊆ Z(H) × Z(K)$

• $Z(H) × Z(K) ⊆ Z(H × K)$

Normally I would post my attempt of the question, but I have no idea where to even start.  Proofs are my kryptonite!

I would be really grateful for pointers!

My attempt:

Choose arbitrary $(h, k) ∈ Z(H × K)$,

For every $(x, y) ∈ H × K$,

$Z(H × K)$ means $(h, k)(x, y) = (x, y)(h, k)$

which equals $(hx, ky) = (xh, yk)$.

Now if we take $h ∈ Z(H)$, for every $x ∈ H$ we get $hx = xh$.

Likewise if we take $k ∈ Z(K)$, for every $y ∈ K$ we get $ky = yk$.

$Z(H) × Z(K) = (hx, ky) = (xh, yk) = Z(H × K)$.

Therefore $Z(H) × Z(K) = Z(H × K)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: For the first, start by choosing an arbitrary $(h,k)\in Z(H\times K)$. What does that mean? It means that for every $(h',k')\in H\times K$ that $(h,k)(h',k') = (h',k')(h,k)$. Expand both sides and see what that requires. Note that saying "for every  $(h',k')\in Z(H\times K)$" is the same as saying "for every $h'\in H'$, $k'\in K'$.

For the second, do something similar. Choose $h\in Z(H)$ and $k\in Z(K)$. Then you need to show that $(h,k)\in Z(H\times K)$, so choose an arbitrary element $(h',k')\in H\times K$ and show that $(h,k)(h',k') = (h',k')(h,k)$.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Comment: Also is $(h', k')$ the same as $(x, y)$ in the question?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my original question with an attempt, let me know what you think!  Thanks for you hint, it was really helpful.